# Ошибка «Невозможно преобразовать параметр из "char *" в "LPCWSTR"»

Tags: c++, opengl

Здравствуйте. По туториалам NeHe учу OpenGL. При компиляции исходника десятого урока с загрузкой 3D мира выдает ошибку:

> source.cpp(112): error C2664: auxDIBImageLoadW: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "char *" в "LPCWSTR"
>   1>          Типы, на которые указывают указатели, не связаны; для преобразования требуется reinterpret_cast, приведение в стиле С или приведение в стиле функции

В чём ошибка? Как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

```
AUX_RGBImageRec *LoadBMP(char *Filename)               
{
    FILE *File=NULL;                             

    if (!Filename)                               
    {
        return NULL;                           
    }

    File=fopen(Filename,"r");                       

    if (File)                                     
    {
        fclose(File);                        
        return auxDIBImageLoad(Filename);       
    }
    return NULL;                                 
}
```

Comment: может лучше листинг кода на [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/) загрузить, ато проскроливать до ответов утомительно

Comment: А где именно в свойствах проекта можно поменять кодировку?

Comment: @Леха Емельяненко `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Character Set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Наверняка у вас в `Visual Studio` в настройках проекта опция `Character Set` установлена в `Unicode`. Если вы замените ее на `Not Set`, то по умолчанию будет использоваться функция `auxDIBImageLoadA`, а не `auxDIBImageLoadW`, что вы, вероятно, и желаете получить.
- Альтернативный вариант - использовать `wchar_t` вместо `char` в ваших функциях загрузки ресурсов, использующих `glaux`.

Answer (score 0):

auxDIBImageLoad хочет указатель на тип wchar_t. Кодировку менять не рекомендую, ибо это может повлиять на подобные функции (MessageBox, например). Можно просто преобразовать строку в формате char *в формат wchar_t* с помощью функции wsprintf. Кстати, с её помощью можно формировать строки с числами для MessageBox'ов, что может пригодиться при отладке.