# Ошибка в коде " аргумент типа "char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR" "

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char

Делаю проект в Visual Studio, и выдает ошибку "аргумент типа "char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"", раньше я просто мог в настройках решения просто поставить, в "Набор символов", "Использовать многобайтовую кодировку", но сейчас попробовав сделать, как я всегда и делал, то у меня все-равно остается ошибка[image: Свойства]
[image: Код программы]
[image: Ошибки]

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//Разборщик аргументов

char buf[100] = {}; //Строка для передачи. Расчитываю на то, что путь к директории не больше 99 символов. Первый символ использую для записи опции -r
strcpy(buf, "0"); //"Инициализация" переменной, отведенной под опцию -r
int numPipe = 0; //Индекс в argv, по которому лежит название Pipe
int numPath = 0; //Индекс в argv, по которому лежит директория
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) { //Цикл считывает каждую переданный аргумент поочередно
    if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-r")) strcpy(buf, "1"); //Если передана опция -r, провожу перезапись строки. "Иницилазиация" переменной для -r
    else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-d")) numPath = i + 1; //Записываю в numPath индекс.
    else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-c")) numPipe = i + 1; //Записываю в numPipe индекс.
}
if (!numPath || !numPipe) {
    printf("Client: Empty arguments for directory or Pipe");
    return -1;
}

//char namePipe[] = "\\\\.\\pipe\\newPipe";

strcat(buf, argv[numPath]);

//Открытие NamedPipe для записи

HANDLE pipe = CreateFile(argv[numPipe], GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Client: Can't find named pipe\n");
    return -1;
}
else printf("Client: %s found\n", argv[numPipe]);

WriteFile(pipe, buf, 100, NULL, NULL);

//Открытие NamedPipe для чтения
WaitNamedPipe(argv[numPipe], NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT);
ReadFile(pipe, buf, 100, NULL, NULL);

if (!CloseHandle(pipe)) {
    printf("Server: can't close pipe\n");
    return -1;
}
printf("%s bytes\n", buf);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Во-первых не следует приводить текст в виде картинки. А во-вторых для вызова функций использовать Юникод кодировку, широкие версии функций (с суффиксом W) и `wchar_t` вместо `char`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка «Невозможно преобразовать параметр из "char \*" в "LPCWSTR"»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/118561/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-char-%d0%b2-lpcwstr)

Comment: А можно ли как-нибудь обойтись без использования `wchar_t`?

Comment: Ну в том или ином виде он тут все равно будет задействован. Обычная файловая система NTFS хранит имена файлов в wchar_t, API для работы с файлами соответственно тоже. Даже если вызвать `CreateFileA` (принимающую `char const *`) имя будет внутри преобразовано в широкие символы.

Comment: Тогда как у меня получилось раньше не использовать `wchar_t`? Странная штука..

Comment: По идее, без директивы `UNICODE` макрос `CreateFile` должен раскрываться в `CreateFileA`.

Comment: СТранно, этот код я делал на другой машине, но там все работало, а  как перешел на другую, то начали выдавать такие ошибки

Comment: Вы что-то недоговариваете. Если у вас действительно так настроен проект, то такой ошибки быть не может. Скорее всего где-то явно прописано `UNICODE`.

Comment: У вас настройки на картинке для платформы x64 - а в IDE текущая платформа X86

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Я поставил Win32, и мне не помогло, увы

Comment: Ооооо, я решил проблему)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Так как решили-то?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Зашел в  диспетчер конфигураций и изменил активную платформу решений на x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я исправил ошибку: 
Зашел в свойства проекта > Диспетчер конфигураций 
Далее в `активная платформа решения` изменил на x64, потом ниже есть таблица проектов данного решения, там я изменил платформу на ту же самую что я и ставил в `активная платформа решения` (на x64), и все заработало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А мне не помогло, есть ещё варианты?